# Backbone Model triggers event conditionally, View doesn't hear it

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm creating a Geolocation Model, fetching from localStorage, and checking if I have there is a latitude property there. If there isn't, a `'geolocation:city_state_blank'` event is triggered. If `'geolocation:city_state_blank'` is heard, `@get_users_geolocation()` is fired.

```
class App.GeoLocation extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: ->

       @on 'geolocation:city_state_blank', -> @get_users_geolocation()

       @fetch().always => 
         if @get('city_state').length is 0
           @trigger 'geolocation:city_state_blank'
         else
           @trigger('geolocation:done')




    get_users_geolocation: =>
        # Code to get / save (in localStorage) a users geolocation and city / state
        @trigger('geolocation:done')
```

After `get_users_geolocation()` is done the event `geolocation:done` is triggered.

I've removed details of fetching the users geoLocation / reverse Geolocation lookups, which are all asynchronous. But the end result of all that work boils down to triggering the `geolocation:done` event.

```
class App.GeolocationView extends Backbone.View
   initialize: =>
      @listenTo @model, 'geolocation:done', =>
        alert('geolocation:done was heard in the view!!!!')
```

## Here is the problem:

In the scenario when the Geolocation model fetches from localStorage and determines the property `latitude` is **not set**, and thus calls `get_users_geolocation` — the View alerts geolocation:done was heard in the view!!!!

But in the scenario when Geolocation has a latitude property (the else), and triggers the `geolocation:done` right away, the View **does not** alert anything. The view doesn't hear it.

I've console.logged the hell out of this, and can say the flow paths are working. The if/else are working and the View is getting instantiated correctly. Logging within the callback after fetching from localStorage yields this..

```
@fetch().always => 
    console.log @get('current_city_state')
    console.log typeof @get('current_city_state')
    // Norfolk, VA
    // String
```

So, there is data there..

What is going on?? Help please!!

Comment: Yea man, one of the best..

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that the `latitude` property of your `App.GeoLocation` is a single number. That would leave your test looking like this:

```
if some_number.length is 0
```

Numbers don't have `length` properties so `@get('latitude').length` will be undefined and you're left with:

```
if undefined is 0
```

That will always be false so `@trigger('geolocation:done')` always gets called.

If you're interested in the existence of the `latitude` property, then CoffeeScript's existential operator (`?`) will server you better:

```
if @get('latitude')?
    # There is a latitude.
else
    # No latitude.
```

To see how `?` behaves you could have a look at what this does:

```
class M extends Backbone.Model

m = new M(p: 0)

if m.get('p') == 0
    console.log('p == 0')
else
    console.log('p != 0')
if m.get('p')?
    console.log('there is a p')
else
    console.log('the p is a lie')
if m.get('no')?
    console.log('yes no')
else
    console.log('no no')
```

That will give you `p == 0`, `there is a p`, and `no no`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qmBNy/

Comment: Oops. I actually simplified my example for SO, the value being returned is a String. I'll update my question. Thanks for the seeing that.

Comment: @Gnee: So what is the `city_state` property coming out as? `null`? `undefined`? An empty string?

Comment: I've updated my question with console.logs. Its coming back as 'Norfolk, Va'

Comment: Is it possible that from within the View, the `@model` which fetches from localStorage triggers 'geolocation:done' much quicker, and the View misses it? In the case of the `@model` doing much asynchronous network calls, the 'geolocation:done' would, I assume fire much later.

Comment: NM, that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: A `fetch` from localStorage isn't (AFAIK) async so the event could be triggered before `initialize` returns. You could try moving the `fetch` out of the `initialize` so that you can create the model, bind to its events, and then fetch (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this. It aint pretty, but it works.

```
@listenTo @model, 'geolocation:done', =>        
   @prefill_location_input()
   @initialize_autocomplete()

@prefill_location_input()
@initialize_autocomplete()
```

I think that your right, the event is triggered before init returns. Here, if Object is ready right away, the `@prefill_location_input()` and `@initialize_autocomplete()` are called, `geolocation:done` will overwrite it in cases its fetched from the network.